# How to create a string from two vectors of strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have two separate vectors of strings:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> vectorA;
vectorA.push_back("a1");
vectorA.push_back("\na2");

std::vector<std::string> vectorB;
vectorB.push_back("b1");
vectorB.push_back("b2");
```

I want to create an `std::string vectorOutput` which shows the following:

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
```

Now, the elements in vector `A` are defined in one class, while the elements in vector `B` come from another class and are read after some code logic happens. The vector sizes are identical. I would like to know what is the best way in C++ to create this new `vectorOutput` string? I was thinking of a loop which iterates over the elements of each vector and appends them to the `vectorOutput`, like:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < vectorA.size() < i++)
{
    vectorOutput += vectorA[i] + vectorB[i];
}
```

In my code these vectors have more elements than presented here. Is there another way to achieve this? Perhaps by creating enums or structs?

Comment: As long as the 2 vectors have the same size, your loop is fine.

Comment: *what is the best way in C++* -- Asking "the best way" is opinion-based.  There is no "best" way.  Maybe bad ways, or good ways, but not "best way".

Comment: Consider using an std::ostringstream instead for better performance

Comment: Yes, these two vectors are meant to be of the same size. I was thinking maybe I could do away with the loop somehow. Initially I just appended text to a string line by line and retrieved vectorA elements one by one, line by line. This looked like an imperfect solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the range-v3 library, you could write it like this:

```
namespace rs = ranges;
namespace rv = ranges::views;
    
auto outputVector = rv::transform(vectorA, vectorB, std::plus{}) 
                  | rv::cache1 
                  | rv::join 
                  | rs::to<std::string>;
```

This has no loops, and is quite readable. Note that `cache1` is needed to make sure that the views returned by `views::transform` are not dangling.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j4fYha).

Comment: That looks clean, however I'm on c++11 at the moment, as well as I intend to stay open source

Comment: @szumial range-v3 is absolutely open source, I would never recommend it otherwise :) But yes, this does need at least C++14 to work.

Comment: I can confirm that this idea works, however, in my application, due to this being a single use-case, I went with an initial idea of a loop described in the question. Thank you for suggesting this library :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about efficiency, this is probably not the best way to do it because you will copy the string each time. It could be better to create a long string directly and to replace some of its characters with the strings you want to concatenate :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str1 = "stringA";
    int len1 = str1.length();
    std::string str2 = "stringB";
    int len2 = str2.length();
    std::string bigString(256, ' ');          //create a container string 
    bigString.replace(0, len1, str1);         //paste a string within it
    bigString.replace(len1 + 1, len2, str2);  //paste a second string after (with a space to separate)
    
    std::cout << bigString << std::endl;      //=>"stringA stringB           ..."

    //resize it when needed
    bigString.resize(512, ' '); 
}
```